# Feature Flag Change Listener (e.g true, false) in Rollout Android SDK

Tags: android, ios, sdk, rollout, launchdarkly

For those who used Rollout SDK's feature flag.

Is it possible to listen / observe  the feature / flag / configuration change in Rollout SDK for iOS / Android by registering for certain flags? For example, I have a deal feature flag, whenever it's enabled or disabled (set to true / false) from Rollout dashboard,  I would like to get a notification about feature flag change or configuration change for whichever I have subscribed. LaunchDarkly SDK provides this feature through

```
 LDClient.get().registerFeatureFlagListener(FEATURE_DEAL, listener)
```

The listener is the instance of FeatureFlagChangeListener interface provided by LaunchDarkly.

```
val listener = FeatureFlagChangeListener { flagKey ->
        //featureFlagHandler?.featureFlagUpdated(flagKey)
    }
```

Does anyone know whether it is possible to achieve the same thing with Rollout SDK. I have read their whole documentation. It has nothing about it and I also could not find anything useful online.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a way?